# Extra blank line when using setspace, wrapfig, and pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, line, setspace, wrapfig

New to LaTex here. I'm sorry if my example text isn't the most minimum it can be.

I need to be able to write documents that are doublespaced, have tables that are single spaced which are inputted from .csv files, and wrap text around the tables.

To that end, I'm using the setspace, wrapfig, and pgfplotstable packages, but when I switch from single space for the tabular back to double space for the text, I get a line break that is triple spaced. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage[nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}

\geometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=1.00in,bottom=1.0in}

\begin{document}

\noindent I have things to say. Important things. Very very very very very very very very very imporant things. My repec score is a billion gagillion trillion. I have things to say. Important things. Very very very very very very very very very imporant things. My repec score is a billion2 

\singlespacing 

\begin{wraptable}{o}{4.25in}
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified, format=hang}
    \caption{Statistic, Variable}
    \label{tab:1}
    \scriptsize
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=semicolon,
    string type,
    %   column type=c,
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule}, after row=\midrule,},
    every row no 0/.style={before row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{All}} \\ }, 
        after row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{} \\ },},
    every row no 1/.style={before row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{Sub group 1}} \\ }, },
    every row no 2/.style={after row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{}} \\ }, },
    every row no 3/.style={before row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{Sub group 2}} \\}, },
    every row no 6/.style={after row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{}} \\ }, },
    every row no 7/.style={before row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{Sub group 3}} \\}, },
    every row no 8/.style={after row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{}} \\ }, },
    every row no 9/.style={before row={\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{Included Covariates:}} \\ }, },
    every last row/.style={
        after row={
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{8}{p{3.6in}}{Note:} },
    },
    columns/r0/.style={column name=, column type=l},
    columns/r1/.style={column name=(73), column type=c},
    columns/r2/.style={column name=\textbf{(74)}, column type=c},
    columns/r3/.style={column name=(75), column type=c},
    columns/r4/.style={column name=(76), column type=c},
    columns/r5/.style={column name=\textbf{(77)}, column type=c},
    columns/r6/.style={column name=\textbf{(78)}, column type=c},
    columns/r7/.style={column name=(79), column type=c},
    ]{example.csv}      
\end{wraptable}

\doublespacing

\noindent gagillion trillion. I have things to say. Important things. Very very very very very very very very very imporant things. My repec score is a billion3. I have things to say. Important things. Very very very very very very very very very imporant things. My repec score is a billion4. I have things to say. Important things. Very very very very very very very very very imporant things. My repec score is a billion5.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  When you switch back to `\doublespacing, you follow that by a blank line.  Try omitting that blank line.  (don't have the ability at the moment to test, so this is a guess.)

Comment: Unfortunately that blank line has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `\singlespacing` command inside the `wraptable` environment?

Comment: OMG. That works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing environmental attributes like font shape and size, or line spacing, and the change isn't meant to be global, it's usually best to restrict the change to the affected environment.

Most LaTeX environments are identified (and input) with
`\begin{<envname>} ... \end{<envname>}`, and are defined as "local groups".  When a group is entered, the attributes of the surrounding environment are saved, and restored when the local group is exited/ended.  So it is almost always safe to enclose a "shape" change in a closed environment with the expectation that this change will disappear when the `\end` is processed.

In the present case, entering `\singlespacing` immediately after `\begin{wraptable}` should have the desired result.